# How does django know which user owns what data?

Tags: python, django

If for example I want to show a zero(0) for all users to see, and I want all users to add one(1) to the number With their Identity only shown for superusers. And how to make sure that each user only can add one time, and of course what is the Security requirements that have to be done to prevent unautohrized Access to change any of this or to get any information?

I understand this is a big topic, but could someone briefly explain for me what parts of Programming that are involved, and maybe some good books on these topics?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The web is stateless. This means that if a browser requests the same page twice, a traditional web server has no real way of knowing if it's the same user.

Enter sessions. Django has an authentication system which requires each user to log in. When the user is logged in they're given a session. A session is made of two parts; A cookie containing a randomly generated token, and a database entry with that same token.

When a user logs in, a new session token is generated and sent, via a cookie, back to the user which the browser stores. At the same time, that record is created in the database. Each time a browser makes a request to Django, it sends its session cookie along with the request and Django compares this to the tokens in the database. If the token exists, the user is considered to be logged in. If the token doesn't exist, the user isn't logged in.

In Django, there are User models which make it easy to check who the currently logged in user is for each request. They're doing all that token checking in the background for us on each and every request made by every user. Armed with this, we can associate other models via "foreign key" relationships to indicate who owns what.

Say you were making a blog where multiple users could write articles. If you wanted to build an editing feature you'd probably want to restrict users to only be allowed to edit their own articles and nobody else's. In this situation, you'd receive the request, find out who the current user was from it, compare that user to the "author" field on the blog Post model and see if that foreign key matches. If it matches, then the user making the current request is the owner and is allowed to edit.

This whole process is secured by the fact that the session tokens are randomly generated hashes, rather than simple ID numbers. A malicious attacker can't simply take the hash and increment the value to try and access adjacent accounts, they'd have to intercept another user's hash entirely. This can be further secured by using SSL certificates so that your connections go over `https://` and all traffic is encrypted between the browser and your server.